# Select feature from GeoJSON based on a node name

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I am working in a geo-data visualization using D3js with a force layout and a Leaflet map. With some help of other users I've been able to build the first version. Now I'm adding a geojson path and I would like to show a specific feature depending on the name of the node I click but right now when I click a node, all the paths show up.

This is what I would like to have:
[image: This is what I would like to have]

This is what I have:
[image]

I tried iterating the paths names in the function I call when I make click on the nodes:

```
        function connectedNodes() {
    var poligono = g.selectAll("path");
    var result = datosPoli.features;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var poligonoNombre = result[i].properties.Name;
    }

    if (toggle == 0) {
  //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
  d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
        r = d3.select(this).datum();

      nodesAll
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", function (o) {
                return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0;
            })
  ;

  lineas
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", function (o) {
                return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 0.5 : 0;
            })
  ;

        poligono
            .filter(function(d){
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var poligonoNombre = result[i].properties.Name;
                    return poligonoNombre;
                }
                return d.id === poligonoNombre;
            })
            .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
        ;

        text
            .transition()
            .style('opacity', function(o){
                    return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0;
        })

        toggle = 1;

} else {
        // devuelve los nodos a la normalidadlos links invisibles
  nodesAll
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", 1)
        ;

  lineas
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", 0)
  ;

        poligono
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
        ;

        text
            .transition()
            .style('opacity', 1)
        ;

  toggle = 0;
}
}
```

But no luck.

I had a problem uploading the complete code to blockbuilder so I uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vp1l9brJ0MzLX3zV4-kyB6-IJEtvFiyB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following is a better polygon check but it looks like none of the names in the legend is found in the names of the Polygons

Better to change the `opacity` in case you want to stroke the polygons. Also change where you create the `red` polygons

```
poligono
    .filter(function (o) { return d.id === o.properties.Name; })
    .attr('opacity', 1);
```

Or a one liner

```
poligono.attr('opacity', o => d.id === o.properties.Name ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: I checked on every name and they're the same. Seems like It works with the first name of the geojson file (because that feature DOES appear when I click the node with the same name) but id doesn't with the rest of features.

Comment: Actually, it appears whenever I click on a node with a name present in the geojson file.

Comment: @PierrePuentes Changed the function. I clicked on the outer circles, but you need to click on the map-circles

Comment: yep!, works perfect: https://i.imgur.com/VnniFao.png. Thank you very much.